# Serve website off personal computer to internal network

Tags: networking, intranet

Is there a way to serve a site off my personal computer to other computers on my network?

I have a website that I created that I would like to have others in the same building be able to access it, but not over the internet. I would also not like to have to purchase a domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have users access a site on your internal network by running some HTTP Server like Apache HTTPD (an easy installer is included in [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)) or Microsoft IIS.

If you go the WampServer route, it has an option for making your site available to other computers ("Put Online"); this exposes the website to any computer which can reach yours.  Other people in your building would be able to type your [local IP address](http://boshdirect.com/blogs/tech/find-local-ip-address.html) into their web browser and access your site.

For example, if your local IP address is 192.168.0.101, users should be able to access your site using a URL like this:  http://192.168.0.101/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. you need to host your web site in your local computer and then others in your local network can access it using the ip address.